# DELETE route using vue-resource and laravel throwing 500 error

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.4, vue-resource

I have a route that will be used to delete an item.

```
Route::delete('items/{item}', 'ItemsController@destroy')->name('admin.items.destroy');
```

I have a vue component that, when a button is clicked, runs this method to delete the item.

```
removeItem() {

    let itemCode = this.item.itemCode;

    this.itemCode = this.item = null;

    this.$http.delete('/items/' + itemCode)
      .then(function(response) {
        this.refreshPage()
      });
  },
```

The result is a 500 internal server error when the request is made.

I have not had much success in finding out why.

Comment: try to remove the first forward slash in your http call like this `this.$http.delete('items/'+ itemCode)`

Comment: tried and it did not work

Comment: got a 403 instead

Comment: could you add your destroy method to your post.

Answer (score 0):

is the `auth` middleware applied on the route? because the error code `403` seems like is forbidden error.

if the `auth` middleware applied on your route send `Authorization` header with the request.

```
{ 
    headers: { 
        Authorization: 'Bearer AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN'
    }
}
```